# Add sp.points key to levelplot colorkey

Tags: r, plot, legend, lattice, levelplot

Is it possible to add the key for, e.g., an `sp.points` layer, to the colorkey generated by `levelplot`?

Take the following example:

```
library(rasterVis)
library(latticeExtra)
library(sp)

r <- as.factor(raster(matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), 10)))
levels(r)[[1]] <- data.frame(ID=0:1, z=c('a', 'b'))
p <- SpatialPoints(matrix(runif(20), 10))

levelplot(r, margin=list(draw=FALSE), scales=list(draw=FALSE),
          col.regions=c('white', 'gray90')) +
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.points(p, pch=20, col=1))
```

[image]

I would like to add a key entry for the points, below the existing colorkey.

A kludgy solution is to add a key to the `levelplot` call as follows, adjusting the `x` and `y` values until it's in the desired location, but (1) finding the right `x` and `y` values is a pain, requiring interaction, (2) the right padding doesn't resize to accommodate the key, and (3) the font size is not automatically scaled to be consistent with the colorkey.

```
k <- list(x = 1.02, y = 0.4, corner = c(0, 0), points=list(pch=20, col=1), 
          text=list('foo', cex=0.9))

levelplot(r, margin=list(draw=FALSE), scales=list(draw=FALSE),
          col.regions=c('white', 'gray90'), key=k) +
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.points(p, pch=20, col=1))
```

[image]

Assuming I need to stick with `lattice` graphics, what's the best way to overcome the issues I listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it does not solve all the issues you raised, maybe the `latticeExtra::mergedTrellisLegendGrob` function is useful for you:

```
p1 <- levelplot(r, scales=list(draw=FALSE),
                col.regions=c('white', 'gray90'))

myPoints <- SpatialPoints(matrix(runif(20), 10))
p2 <- spplot(myPoints, pch=20)

## Merge graphics
p <- p1 + p2

## Merge legends
l1 <- p1$legend$right
l2 <- p2$legend$bottom
ll <- mergedTrellisLegendGrob(l1, l2)
p$legend$right$fun <- ll

p
```

[image: mergedLegends]

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Is it possible to have the`p2` legend in line with the levelplot key (i.e. above or below it, instead of beside it)?

Comment: You should try the argument `vertical` in `mergedTrellisLegendGrob`. Its default value is `FALSE` (as in this example). Exploring its code I found that with `vertical = TRUE` this function uses `packGrob` to put the first legend on the top, and the second one on the bottom. Maybe this is not exactly what you need. Instead you may reuse the last lines of this function using the `row` and `col` arguments of `packGrob`.